# How should I properly block access from other threads to this object?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm doing this little exercise myself trying to understand how should I work with concurrency and threads.

It happens that sometimes I have an object that I can't modify its source code and that is not thread-safe, so I want it to be accessed just by one thread.

In this example that thirdparty object that I can't touch is called Holdeable. What I do is trying to wrap it into a class called Holder that has synchronized methods, and I expect that by doing it only one thread can access that Holdeable object. At sometime I null the reference to the Holdeable object and I want it properly done so when the other thread evaluates mHolder.getHoldeable()==null is true, and avoids entering the code that can cause a NullPointerException.

My last attempt included a synchronized block, which is this:

```
class Holder {
    Holdeable mHoldeable;
    public synchronized void setHoldeable(Holdeable holdeable) { mHoldeable = holdeable; }
    public synchronized Holdeable getHoldeable() { return mHoldeable; }

}

class Holdeable { // Cannot be modified, that would be to cheat :D
    public int someValue;

}
public class MainClass {
    private static Holder mHolder;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Holdeable holdeable = new Holdeable();
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.setHoldeable(holdeable);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while(true) {   
                            synchronized(mHolder) {
                                if(mHolder.getHoldeable() != null) {
                                    Thread.sleep(23);
                                    System.out.println(mHolder.getHoldeable().someValue);
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("No holder!"); 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mHolder.getHoldeable().someValue = 2;
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            mHolder.getHoldeable().someValue = 3;
            Thread.sleep(500);
            mHolder.setHoldeable(null);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



}
```

This example avoids throwing a NullPointerException, but as you can see, it just takes a lot to execute with so much locking. I'm struggling with this while I read the book "The art of concurrency" to see if I finally get it.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe. You have two levels of locking:

1. Holder's methods are synchronized;
2. you synchronize on the Holder instance.

Point 1. doesn't give you enough synchronization because it covers only *fetching* holdeable and not accessing its properties;

Point 2. doesn't give you any synchronization at all because you are acquiring the lock only in one thread.

I suggest you use only point 2. and apply it consistently.

BTW your program takes so long to execute because it calls `Thread.sleep`. The performance of locking is way too high for you to be able to notice it without involving tight loops repeating at least hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: I don't think I understand you. You say neither point 1 nor 2 is synchronizing properly, so why I would use only point 2? Could you explain it better? Thanks :)

Comment: You should use the *approach* as in point 2, but properly implemented by acquiring the lock in all threads. But then you don't really need the wrapper object at all.

Comment: Ohh I see you're right. I haven't acquired the lock in the main one with a synchronized block. So this works without the wrapper, I'm actually locking the holdeable instance. But then I've realized I can't just acquire the lock for the instance without checking first if its null. Then I'll have two if statements checking for the non-nullity of the reference of that instance. Something is still wrong :/ Thanks !

Comment: That's easily fixable: create a `public static final Object lock = new Object()` and use that for locking.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Holder {
  final Holdeable mHoldeable;

  Holder(Holdeable holdeable) {
    this.mHoldeable = Objects.requireNonNull(holdeable, "Holdeable cannot be null");
  }

  Holdeable get() {
    return mHoldeable;
  }
}
```

Using this construct will make your life so much easier. And as you might have noticed: it as well removes the need to synchronize. And if I ever write a book, that would be in it on page one. ;)

Threading and synchronization is done almost 100% on architectural level, adding some synchronized blocks is just a backup/quick & dirty solution.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. How do you exactly are avoiding to modify the properties of the Holdeable instance from more than one thread at once?